# How can I make the application run in the background on flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a lock screen application on flutter for ios and android, I want the application to work in the background, i.e. when the phone screen is turned on, the window for entering the pin code of my application "pops out", how can this be done?

Comment: This can't be done on iOS for sure

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no direct solution on flutter yet. For sure there is no solution for ios. You will have to write both java/kotlin and swift/objective c and use the invoke methods to call your native functions.
native is a word we use for the specific platform code. for example native android means java or kotlin and swift or objective c for ios.